# How to scroll the Scrollview out side the bound

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

Hi in my app needs to display list of images in horizontal list with center focus. It works fine by using `UIScrollView` and `PagingEnable=Yes`; now i could not scroll the content which is displayed out side of `UIScrollView` bound.

How is it possible to scroll the UiscrollView out side bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a container view which is the same height as your images, but is sized so that all images can fit in it. Each image's frame will have an "x" offset that puts it on the end of the image before it. Now lets say your container has 3 images in it, each 320 wide, for a total of 960.

Given that, you have to set the scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 320);

Comment: hi Thanks for replay i have set contentSize and scroll successfully within scrollview. Now i want to scroll out side of scrollview.Because i added clipsToBounds=No;

Answer (score 0):

Here i give the some tutorial for the how to manage the scrollview horizontally which is below.

.h file contain

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arForImages; // array for storing images URL
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrPage; // scroll view used as PageCtr
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet HJManagedImageV *imgV; // Image to display selected
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName; // label to display selected's title
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSUInteger currentPage; // to mantain current page
```

.m file contain

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arForImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.apple.com/in/iphone/iphone-3gs/images/iphone-phone-20100607.jpg",@"http://www.apple.com/in/iphone/iphone-3gs/images/iphone-ibooks-20100607.jpg",@"http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2007/01/apple-iphone-official-1.jpg",@"http://www.dailytechpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/iphone-3G1.jpg",@"http://www.iunlockiphone3g.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Apple-Iphone-India-Launch1.jpg",@"http://st2.gsmarena.com/vv/pics/apple/apple-iphone-3g-01.jpg",@"http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/iphone.jpg",@"http://bindapple.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/can-iphones-get-viruses1.jpg",@"http://www.coolpctips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/iphone-mailbox.jpg",@"http://www.everymac.com/images/other_images/iphone-iphone-3g-comparison.jpg",@"http://iphone4issues.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Iphone-4-Issues1.jpg",nil];

    [self setupImages];
}
```

Pagination for the scrollviews

```
#define kXDistance    5
#define kYDistance    5
#define kThumbWidth   58
#define kThumbHeight   58
#define kTagForImageView    10000

- (void)setupImages {
    // This will remove all subview from your scrollView
    [[self.scrPage subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    // set the content size of your scrollView to number of object that you have in your array
    self.scrPage.contentSize=CGSizeMake((self.arForImages.count+4)*63, 68);

    // we will start from two in this tutorial, you can start from one also.
    NSUInteger i=2; // images starting from location 2
    for (NSString *str in self.arForImages) {
        // buttons will have images within it &amp; we will add buttons to scrollView
        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        NSUInteger xVal=(i+1)*kXDistance;
        xVal = xVal + (i*kThumbWidth);
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, kYDistance, kThumbWidth, kThumbHeight)];
        btn.tag=i-1; // index tagging strating from 1

        HJManagedImageV *imgV=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kThumbWidth, kThumbHeight)];
        imgV.tag=kTagForImageView;
        imgV.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arForImages objectAtIndex:i-2]];
        imgV.clipsToBounds=YES;
        imgV.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        imgV.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        imgV.layer.cornerRadius = 3;

        // here GlobalCacheManager is an object declared in AppDel which is accessed via a Constant
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:imgV];

        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [btn addSubview:imgV];

        [self.scrPage addSubview:btn];
        i++;
    }
    self.lblName.text=[[self.arForImages objectAtIndex:0] lastPathComponent];
    self.imgV.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arForImages objectAtIndex:0]];
    [GlobalCacheManager manage:self.imgV];
    self.currentPage = 0;
}

- (void)btnTapped:(UIButton*)btn {
    self.scrPage.delegate=nil;
    CGRect rectToScroll = btn.frame;
    rectToScroll=CGRectMake(rectToScroll.origin.x-63-63, kYDistance, 320, 68);
    [self.scrPage scrollRectToVisible:rectToScroll animated:YES];
    self.lblName.text=[[self.arForImages objectAtIndex:btn.tag-1] lastPathComponent];
    self.imgV.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arForImages objectAtIndex:btn.tag-1]];
    [GlobalCacheManager manage:self.imgV];
    [self.scrPage performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.3];
}
```

Hope this may helping to you.